# How do I check if hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

When selector A is clicked or outside of selector B I want selector B to `.toggle()`. That has been pretty straight forward.

However I don't want selector B to `.toggle()` back unless selector A is clicked - not when you click outside of selectors A or B. That is the part I can't figure out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Container = $(".redBar"); // Container (selector A)

  function Toggle() {
    Container.toggleClass("hide"); // Toggle Container with display none selector [to hide selector B]
  }

  // If selector B is visible
  if ($(Container).is(":visible")) {
    // On click of the document and selector A
    $(document, ".toggleBar").on("click", function(event) {
      // If the target of the click isn't selector A nor a descendant of selector A
      if (!Container.is(event.target) && Container.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        Toggle();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
/* Selector A */
.toggleBar {
  width: 150px;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggleBar:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Selector B */
.redBar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redBarContainer">
  <!-- selector A -->
  <div class="toggleBar">toggle bar</div>

  <!-- selector B -->
  <div class="redBar"></div>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/brilliantmojo/pen/GRoyrKg

Comment: `$(document, ".toggleBar").on("click", function(event) {` does not make sense. Not sure why you would be using a context of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply record click on the whole document and just the `.toggleBar` saperately and make it work as you want

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target !== $('.redBar')[0]) {
      $('.redBar').addClass('hide');
    }
});
$(".toggleBar").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.redBar').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
/* Selector A */
.toggleBar {
  width: 150px;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggleBar:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Selector B */
.redBar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redBarContainer">
  <!-- selector A -->
  <div class="toggleBar">toggle bar</div>

  <!-- selector B -->
  <div class="redBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description of what you're trying to do, a much more simple approach is to attach the `toggle()` call to the click of the `.toggleBar` element and then just `hide()` when a click occurs outside of the elements, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $redBar = $('.redBar');

  $('.toggleBar').on('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $redBar.toggle();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', (e) => {
    if ($redBar[0] !== e.target)
      $redBar.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Selector A */
.toggleBar {
  width: 150px;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggleBar:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Selector B */
.redBar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redBarContainer">
  <!-- selector A -->
  <div class="toggleBar">toggle bar</div>

  <!-- selector B -->
  <div class="redBar"></div>
</div>
```